# Safari and mobile Safari randomly missing images BUG?

Tags: html, css, image, safari

Im trying to figure out why we randomly misses images when looking on mobile safari and desktop safari. Google  Chrome is always working for me.

Is this a bug or is there anything i can change to make it render all the images. It is totaly random and never had this problem before.

http://www.fantasticfrank.se/stockholm/till-salu

[image: Missing images to the right in safari, working to the left in chrome]
[image: Error in console resources tab in safari]

Comment: any errors logged in the console?

Comment: Nop nothing in the console.

Comment: Wonder if there can be anything with cachening in Safari.